# How to input text into array of strings?

Tags: c++, string, input

string fruits[200];

How can I input a string into the array ?

```
Example:
My mom has apples;
So , fruits array will contain:
fruits[0] = "My";
fruits[1] = "mom";
..........etc.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Where is the input coming from? User input or from a pre-defined string?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: User input for example : cin>>number;

Comment: I've tried the getline function but it doesn't work.

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" isn't helpful. You have to show us exactly what you tried, tell us what you expected to happen, and what happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're reading from the standard input:

```
int i = 0;
for (string word; cin >> word; i++)
    names[i] = word;
```

If you're reading from a `string`, use `istringstream` instead.

Comment: okay but this will infinite loop , how can I stop this and continue to the other instructions ?

Comment: @Johnnie `cin >> word` will return `false` when there's no more word to read. Try it :-)

Comment: I've tried if(word == null) break; else names[i] = word; but I get no match for operator == in word==0; what's wrong?

Comment: Fwiw, unless you have a specific reason to examine the intermediate `word` prior to insertion, this can be reduced further to simply `int i=0; while (cin >> names[i]) ++i;`

Comment: @WhozCraig `while (cin >> names[i++]) ;` would be even shorter but I was writing it with `vector` in my mind :-)

Comment: @XiaoJia I believe `while (cin >> names[i++])` may be incorrect, as I believe even in failure the post-increment is applied, in which case your resulting count will always be off by one. Someone check me on that.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're absolutely right! but i suppose he doesn't need `i` here :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use the standard C++ library to its fullest, use input iterators and a `vector<string>` instead of an array:

```
vector<string> words;
back_insert_iterator< vector<string> > back_iter (words);
istream_iterator<string> eos;
istream_iterator<string> iit (cin);
copy (iit, eos, back_iter);
```

Using `vector<string>` fixes the problem of having to guess how many words would be entered, and living with the consequences of making a wrong guess.

Answer (score 0):

The most compact solution:

```
vector<string> words; 
copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin), 
     istream_iterator<string>(), 
     back_inserter(words));
```

This is @dasblinkenlight's solution, written using temporary variables.